# macOS 11.6 "DST Root CA X3" certificate warnings

Tags: security, keychain, certificate

System: macOS 11.6.1

For an internal domain with Let's Encrypt, I am still getting outdated certificate warnings on Safari and Chrome. Firefox with its own store is fine.
I checked Keychain Access and "ISRG Root X1" is installed in System Roots set to "Allways trust".

I searched in Keychain Access for "DST Root CA X3", filtering set to "All Items" in all four keychains I can see on the left hand side, "login", "Login Items", "System" and "System Roots", but nothing came up.

Running this command

```
$ security find-certificate -a -c "DST Root CA X3" /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
```

I get

```
keychain: "/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain"
version: 256
class: 0x80001000
attributes:
    "alis"<blob>="DST Root CA X3"
    "cenc" ...
    ...
```

Does that mean the outdated certificate is still in System Roots, even though I can't find it in the Keychain Access app?

Anything else I can try to fix this?